# I am trying to retrieve HTML Node.js to my react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

[image]I currently have a Node.js script that is getting html data from a website and putting it onto a local host server. I have that aspect working but I can't retrieve the HTML from my react app. I want to get the data from UND website and then be able to display some of the headlines onto my own website home page. My question is why am I not able to retrieve the HTML from my server into my react app.

Below is my react app

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
const [html, setHtml] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get("https://localhost:3000")
    .then((response) => {
        setHtml(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("An error occurred:", error);
    });
}, []);

return <div>{html}</div>;
}




export default Home;
```

Below this is my Node.js file that is getting the html that I want.

```
    const express = require("express");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.post("/post", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Connected to react");
    res.redirect("/");
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const website = "https://und.com";

let options = {
headers: {
    "user-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36"
}
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
// Make the HTTP request using axios
axios(website, options)
.then(({data}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const result = $(".post__meta h3 a:last-child")
    .map((_, e) => $(e).text().trim())
    .get();
    console.log(result);
    // Use cheerio to manipulate the HTML data

    // Set the content type of the response to "text/html"
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");

    // Send the HTML data as the response
    res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // The HTTP request failed
        console.log("An error occurred:", error);
    
        // Set the status code of the response to indicate an error
        res.status(500);
    
        // Send an error message as the response
        res.send("An error occurred while making the HTTP request.");
    });
    })

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on PORT: ${PORT} `);
})
```

Comment: I am not very good at this stuff yet and don’t know where most of the parsing should be done. I was going to get all the html to my front end and then parse it. However, End goal is to have the articles and pictures from und.com displayed on my front end and linked to the articles

Comment: OK, well I gave you the selector to get the headlines in the previous post. I thought this question was going to be a Cheerio question about getting the pictures as well, which I don't see an attempt at solving here. `setHTML` isn't going to work, BTW, you'll need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. There are a lot of missing steps here--I suggest breaking the problem down into small pieces, then work on solving each simpler problem specifically and building up the solution piece by piece.

Comment: My main focus was to get the html to my front end and confirm I have that done. Once I have that done then get only the correct info to my front end.

Comment: What do I need to do to get the front end to retrieve the html?

Comment: Did you try using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and skipping Cheerio as I suggested? What's the current problem? I assume it's that the HTML is presented as plain text in your React app. If it's something else, please state what the problem is specifically.  If you only want to deal with some of the HTML, it [probably doesn't make sense to send the whole document over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Much of its content won't show up properly on your site since it's cross-origin.

Comment: The current problem is that there is an axios error when trying to get the html into my current react app. I changed my code above to utilize the parsing you did earlier. my server now only displays the titles of the articles and I will later work on getting more information such as pictures. I just need to the html from server to react app

Comment: What's the axios error? If your Express and React apps aren't connected, then the HTML and parsing is irrelevant. I've said it a few times, but you need to clarify a single, specific problem, otherwise the question is off topic. If you parse the titles and info you want from the HTML server-side, then you don't need to worry about sending the HTML from the server to React as I mentioned above.

Comment: I currently have a list displaying on the server that shows the titles of the pages. I want to get this list to my react app.

Comment: That's fine, but please share the axios error you're experiencing so I can understand what problem you're asking for help with. After changing the code in the question, your HTML response doesn't make sense. You probably want to send JSON like you were doing in your last post.

Comment: I have added a picture with the axios error I am getting

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Is your server running?

Comment: Yes my server is running and displaying on my local host 3000

Comment: Can you send me a direct message?

Comment: alright I posted job so you can message me and we can work together my user name is rpuhalsk

Answer (score 0):

Just use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://dangerouslySetInnerHTML).

So replace this:

```js
return <div>{html}</div>;
```

With this:

```js
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
```

**But pay attention that setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.**

Comment: Im still getting an axios error when running it and nothing shows up.

Comment: Instead of this line `return <div>{html}</div>;`

Comment: any other help?